# How to force symbols to break line in textbox

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text, richtext

I generate text on runtime and I need my textbox NOT to break symbols such as "+" or "/". It will break the line just fine with words, but text such as "+3/+3" isn't considered a whole word so it breaks.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfQPv.png)
Any way of forcing the textbox to treat those symbols as a whole word?
I'm using TMPro text in Unity.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro@4.0/manual/RichTextNoBreak.html). TMPro supports rich text and they have a tag for such a thing. The example in the link shows a word with whitespace between its letters yet it's not broken up. This won't be a general rule, but you can control what is considered a "whole word" on demand.

Rich text is very convenient sometimes.

Comment: Thank you so much!
This is exactly what I was looking for!
I figured richtext had a tag of some sort for this but I couldn't find it for the life of me!